# Adding an Array of INT column where each value is a primary key from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, many-to-many

Given two tables like so

```
CREATE TABLE participants(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name TEXT NOT NULL,
    Title TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE meetings (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Organizer TEXT NOT NULL,
    StartTime DATE NOT NULL,
    EndTime DATE NOT NULL,
    Participants INT[],
);
```

I want Participants column of 'meetings' table to contain set of integers which are all primary keys (specific participant) from 'participants' table.

How do I define this field in 'meetings' table ?

Comment: Why can't you create a meetings_participants table?

Comment: @SalmanA what do you mean ? Im quite new to SQL could you explain further ?

Comment: Personally, I would avoid using array features of PostgreSQL and create a many-many table that stores (meeting, participant) pairs. Foreign key and unique constraints could easily be added.

Comment: @SalmanA could you write an example from my tables ? I could probably grasp it if I see it in code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old fashioned way is to create a many-many table, with a couple of commonsense constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE meetings_participants(
    meeting_id int not null,
    participant_id int not null,
    primary key (meeting_id, participant_id),
    foreign key(meeting_id) references meetings(id),
    foreign key(participant_id) references participants(id)
)
```

Now it is easy to add and remove people to meetings be inserting or deleting rows or query meetings that e.g. have 4 or more participants.

Comment: thank you'! So if i understand correctly, I remove participants column from my meetings table. I have just meetings table and participants table, and this unifying table holds meeting and participant pairs per row ?

Comment: Exactly. This is a many-to-many/bridge table. In future it'll allow you to store additional information in that table (e.g. which participant is/are the host, which participant actually attended the meeting etc).

Answer (score 1):

A more common approach is to create a junction table for the meeting participants.

```
CREATE TABLE participants (
  participant_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  Name TEXT NOT NULL,
  Title TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE meetings (
  meeting_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  Organizer TEXT NOT NULL,
  StartTime DATE NOT NULL,
  EndTime DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE meeting_participants(
  meeting_id INT NOT NULL, 
  participant_id INT NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (meeting_id, participant_id), 
  FOREIGN KEY (meeting_id) REFERENCES meetings(meeting_id), 
  FOREIGN KEY (participant_id) REFERENCES participants(participant_id)
);
```

Which is then used to join the 2 tables.
For example:

```
SELECT m.*, p.*
FROM meeting_participants mp
JOIN meetings m USING(meeting_id)
JOIN participants p USING(participant_id)
WHERE m.Organizer = 'John Doe';
```